# Clusters on separate pages of pdf. Each row may belong to different clusters

Tags: r

As title says I would like to save each cluster on separate page of pdf file.

Example data:

```
structure(list(P1 = c("ATCG00490", "AT5G17710", "AT2G42910", 
"AT4G23600", "AT3G61540", "AT2G05990"), P2 = c("AT5G38420", "AT5G20070", 
"AT5G04230", "AT1G08200", "AT4G30910", "AT5G52100"), clique = structure(list(
    `930` = integer(0), `2090` = integer(0), `3120` = c(2L, 3L, 
    231L), `3663` = integer(0), `3704` = integer(0), `4156` = c(19L, 
    27L)), .Names = c("930", "2090", "3120", "3663", "3704", 
"4156"), class = "AsIs")), .Names = c("P1", "P2", "clique"), row.names = c(930L, 
2090L, 3120L, 3663L, 3704L, 4156L), class = "data.frame")
```

Some of the rows belong to many clusters and some of them just to single one. Of course all possible variants have to be considered.

If it's possible I would like to keep only clusters which have at least two members.

That's the function which I use if each of the row belongs to single cluster:

```
pdf("clusters.pdf", , width=12, height=18)
lapply(split(data_cluster, data_cluster$cluster), function(d) {
  grid::grid.newpage()
  gridExtra::grid.table(d)
}
)
dev.off()
```

Maybe it will help someone to find an answer for me.

EDIT:

I made a mistake while preparing an example data... Please take a look on my original data and than you will find out that's not that simple (at least in my opinion).

```
structure(list(P1 = c("ATCG00490", "AT5G17710", "AT2G42910", 
"AT4G23600", "AT3G61540", "AT2G05990"), P2 = c("AT5G38420", "AT5G20070", 
"AT5G04230", "AT1G08200", "AT4G30910", "AT5G52100"), clique = structure(list(
    `930` = integer(0), `2090` = integer(0), `3120` = c(2L, 3L, 
    231L), `3663` = integer(0), `3704` = integer(0), `4156` = c(19L, 
    27L)), .Names = c("930", "2090", "3120", "3663", "3704", 
"4156"), class = "AsIs")), .Names = c("P1", "P2", "clique"), row.names = c(930L, 
2090L, 3120L, 3663L, 3704L, 4156L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is the difference? That the clusters now are in data_cluster$clique, that it is a list rather than a character vector, and that some observation have no cluster? In that case, my solution works with this : `data_cluster$clique <- sapply(data_cluster$clique,paste,collapse = ",")
data_cluster <- cSplit(indt = d,splitCols = "clique",sep=",", direction = "long",)`

Comment: It works like it supposed to. Thx!

Comment: Are you really just trying to get a list column to a long form? If so, `library(splitstackshape); listCol_l(data_cluster, "clique")` should do it, as should `library(tidyr); unnest(data_cluster, "clique")`. I'm not sure I follow the part of your question about what you want to plot on each page of the PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is only a question of splitting a variable to a long format data.frame. `library(splitstackshape)` does just that. Here is a solution using @Ananda's suggestion of `listCol_l` rather than `cSplit`.

```
library(splitstackshape)

data_cluster <- listCol_l(data_cluster, "clique")
data_cluster <- data_cluster[,n := .N >= 2,by=clique_ul][!is.na(clique_ul) & n,][,n :=NULL]

pdf("clusters.pdf", width=12, height=18)
lapply(unique(data_cluster$clique_ul), function(i) {
  grid::grid.newpage()
  gridExtra::grid.table(data_cluster[clique_ul == i,])
})
dev.off()
```

This will produce an empty pdf document with your dataset, since no cluster is repeated.

Comment: My bad... because the example is not the same like my original data.. please take a look on the edit in 2 mins...